# R Shiny Dataframe Image Embed

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

[image]

I have this a dataframe called Order23. One of the columns is called Order23$Team, next to the team name I want to display the teams logo. Do I need to save each teams logo into  a www folder? I'm looking to display that dataframe in R Shiny. Any help would be appreciated.

Need Help Please.....

Comment: Without reprex (reproducible example), it's difficult to answer. Look at this link https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

In your DT datatable you'd need to use `escape = FALSE`:

```
require(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- DT::dataTableOutput('df')

Order23 <- data.frame(
  Team = c('Pittsburg', 'Washington', 'Detroit'),
  Logo = c('<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Pittsb_steelers_uniforms17.png" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Washington_Redskins_uniforms.png" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Jets_uniforms12.png" height="52"></img>')
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$df <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(Order23, escape = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've put some online links for the logos but if you want to read the logos from a file yes you have to put them in the WWW subfolder and read the particular logo based on the Team variable values.